# Visual Studio 2022 is "killing" my Python (3.9.13, 32 bit) installation. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip, mingw

I am using Windows 10 and have been using different versions of Python 3 in 32 bit for a long time. Currently the 3.9.13. I am forced to use a 32 bit version, because I have to use 32 bit dlls to control devices.

So far everything has worked great.  For another project I had to install MS Visual Studio 2022. Since then pip tries to use the 64 bit compiler of Visual Studio 2022 when installing new packages if something has to be compiled.

I then get the error message "Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Program python found: YES (C:\Python\python.exe)
Need python for x86_64, but found x86".

I've been trying to solve this problem for days without success!

I tried to install MinGW as an alternative compiler. With MinGW64 I get the same error message. I read that by setting CXXFLAGS=-m32, CFLAGS=-m32, LDFLAGS=-m32 you can bring the compiler to 32 bit. However, I always get the error message "meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Compiler gcc cannot compile programs."

After that I tried to install MinGW32. This SEEMED to work as well. However, packages like SciPy now give me "C compiler for the host machine: gcc (gcc 6.3.0 "gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0") when installing using pip.
C linker for the host machine: gcc ld.bfd 2.28
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 6.3.0 "c++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.28

...

meson.build:45:4: ERROR: Problem encountered: SciPy requires GCC >= 8.0".
Apparently a newer gcc version is needed. But I did not find it as MinGW32 for Windows. I'm starting to get a bit desperate :/

Comment: Don't use just "pip", use whatever python interpreter is called + `-m pip`. E.g. `py -m pip` or `py -3.9 -m pip` - I'm using py since you're on windows, you should probably check `py -0` to list your python versions and see which is selected as default